# Jquery pagination revised without images preload

Tags: jquery, pagination, preload

I use the jQuery Pagination revised to pagination a pages in my project, it's more fast than used by ajax PHP, tutorial : http://www.xarg.org/2011/09/jquery-pagination-revised/, it has a revised status , when we click forward and back buttons from the browser , we can get the previous paginated page. The problem is with a big number of items (more than 500 items to paginate) , it takes more time to preload all items before pagination . Is there any solution to ignore the preload action with this plug in???

Thank you for your suggestion...

Comment: As i saw, this plugin cannot be modified , it's based on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was : change the plug in to another like using ajax pagination anchor.